# How to encrypt/prevent images from being downloaded straight from browser?

Tags: javascript, image, encryption

I am creating an application that is transmitting images but the way basic javascript works the images can potentially be downloaded straight from the console in JS. I wanted to know if there is a solution for transmitting images that can't be downloaded from the console. I have seen topics about encrypted media extensions that are used by such as netflix. Is this a solution for what I have described? If so how do you use it with a library such as React?

Comment: Have you considered that someone can take a screenshot of what's showing on the browser?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's appropriate to answer this way, but there is not a true way of preventing images from being downloaded from the browser. For the user to see an image served by your website, it has to be loaded into the browser's memory. While there are tricks to prevent a simple right-click and "Save," your question is asking if it's possible to prevent transmitted images from being saved via console (or in general, it seems). The answer to that is "no", since its presence in memory opens it up to all manner of copying it. Could be a simple screenshot or getting it from the dev tools sources tab or via console script.